# __doPostBack is not a function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MedicalCategory.aspx.cs" Inherits="SanatanJeevan.MedicalCategory" %>

        <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" runat="server">
            <link href="assets/admin/pages/Prescription.css" rel="stylesheet" />

               <script>
                //update button click
                var btnUpdate = document.getElementById('<%= btnUpdate.ClientID %>');
                $(function () {
                    $("[id*=btnDelete]").removeAttr("onclick");
                    $('#dialogMedicalCategory').text("Are you sure you want to update?");
                    $('#dialogMedicalCategory').dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: "Alert",
                        resizable: true,
                        height: "auto",
                        width: 400,
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                $("[id*=btnUpdate]").attr("rel", "delete");
                                $("[id*=btnUpdate]").click();
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            },
                            cancel: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                return false;
                            }
                        },
                        open: function () {
                            $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').find('button').remove();
                            $('.ui-dialog-buttonset').find('button').removeClass('ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover').addClass('btn btn-danger');
                        }
                    });

                    $(btnUpdate).click(function (e) {
                        if ($(this).attr("rel") != "delete") {
                            $('#dialogMedicalCategory').dialog('open');
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            __doPostBack(this.name, '');
                            //return true;
                        }
                    });
                });

    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CssClass=" btn btn-success" runat="server" Style="display: none" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
```

__doPostBack(this.name, ''); is not a function error was thrown, while click on ok button,while iam using in aspx page it will working fine but when i am using master page only it shown the error. i am suffering from this error on last 5 days please help me.

Comment: where are you calling this function ?/

Comment: From my view, you're missed a `</script>` closing tag before `<asp:Button>`. If the problem still persists after adding closing script tag, try to add `ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference` on code behind (may be extended to an answer later).

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
SubmitBehavior="false"
```

property in button.
It will working fine.